# TypeScript type static methods

Tags: typescript

I was just wondering whether it is possible to type static methods/properties on classes using `implements`, since that seems to type the instance of the class (non-static methods/properties) only. E.g.

```
type Foo = {
  doSomething(): void;
};

// This works
class Bar implements Foo {
  doSomething() {
    return;
  }
}

// Class 'Baz' incorrectly implements interface 'Foo'.
// Property 'doSomething' is missing in type 'Baz' but required in type 'Foo'.
class Baz implements Foo {
  static doSomething() {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: you've defined doSomething as a static method. Static methods are associated with the class, not an instance of the class. Therefore, doSomething is not considered an instance method of Baz, and does not satisfy the Foo interface requirement.

Comment: Yep, thanks! Shame it's only possible with decorators.

Comment: There are various workarounds, some of which do not involve decorators; see the answers to both linked questions above